# Why doesn't this class hierarchy fluent mapping work?

Tags: nhibernate, class, mapping, hierarchy, fluent

What's wrong with my mapping shown below? Is this a problem with GeneratedBy.Foreign()? How should I use it cause my PK in UserTable(UID) is also the FK which refers to PersonTable PK(PID). I get the Duplicate class/entity mapping consoleMappingTest.SystemUser error. what do you suggest(be sure to look at database structure- no way to change it). thanks.

Inheritance structure:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
}

public class User:Person
{
    public override int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ID;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ID = value;
        }
    }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Salary { get; set; }
}

public class SystemUser:User
{
    public virtual int Password { get; set; }
}
```

Database structure:

for saving some info about person(some fields not shown here):

```
PersonTable(PID)
```

for saving User and all it's subclasses like system user:

```
UserTable(UID,Name,Salary,Type)
```

and here is my mapping:

```
 public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Table("PersonTable");
        Id(x => x.ID, "PID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();//or HiLo-not important
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("UserTable");
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type").Default("U");
        Id(x => x.ID, "UID").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Person");//how should use this?
        Map(x => x.Salary);
        Join("PTable", j =>
        {
            j.KeyColumn("UID");
            j.Map(x => x.Name);
        });
    }
}

public class SystemUserMap : SubclassMap<SystemUser>
{
    public SystemUserMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("SU");
        Map(x => x.Password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Foreign("")` is meant to point to a Reference (Property with another mapped entity) from which the Id should be retrieved. You don't have a Reference to class `Person` named `Person` so you can't use it like this.

**you already asked the same question with an answer. I know i didn't do it right first shot but would be nice if you told me what doesnt work with the latest edit or you dont like the solution befor asking the same question again**